# Change the price of in-app purchase item after publishing android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

Is it possible to change in-app purchase item's price after it has been published in Google Play? (I'm assuming the app has been published, too).

The whole documentations online at http://developer.android.com as well as http://support.google.com/googleplay/ have nothing about it, only mentioning the possibility of changing price of an app, not the in-app item.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes you can change prices at will.

Comment: But can you change the in-app price without releasing a new APK onto the Market?

Comment: Yes. The apk is a separate entity. Just update the price in the Developer Console and press "Save". It might take an hour or so to propagate around all the servers but its usually quite quick.

Answer (score 3):

You change the prices on the Developer console not in the application, of course if you have graphics/text in the app that shows prices you need to figure out how to update those, maybe pull them from a server?
See: [Billing Catalog](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-catalog)
and [Billing Testing](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can change prices of managed and unmanaged in-app products, but NOT for subscriptions. This is because users will always see the latest price of products as they purchase them, so changing the price of a managed/unmanaged product is fine. However, customers who have already purchased a subscription and agreed to a certain price per month (or per year) cannot be made to pay a different price without knowing it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that the pricing policy has changed meanwhile. The current docs warn:

> Warning: You cannot change the price of an in-app product after you make it available for purchase.

https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_overview

Any recent experience on this?

Comment: As a friend developer, this warning only applies to subscriptions. So one-time in app purchases can be changes.