# Change price of subscription product in android app

Tags: android, in-app-billing, subscription

I have an android app published in play store with subscription product charged yearly.
I have used to old In-App billing API.
Now I want to change the price of the subscription product.

I think I will need to change the price of subscription product in Developer console. Is that option available for old In-App Billing API.

What should I do ?

Answer (score 8):

If you have published the products as subscription I suppose you can not change the item's price once you have published it. An option is that you can publish a new subscription product ID at a new price, then offer it in your app instead of the original product. Users who have already purchased will continue to be charged at the original price, but new users will be charged at the new price. Also you can remove the old subscription product from the product list offered in your app to prevent users from seeing or purchasing it. For more information kindly check: http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions.html.

Comment: I saw that android doc link but was confused by this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10297238/change-the-price-of-in-app-purchase-item-after-publishing-android

It also seems correct to me.

Comment: I think you can change the price of managed and un-managed in-app products from the developer console but for subscription I think the above mentioned method is only possible.

Comment: Will it have any effect on the old users who have purchased subscriptions ? Also removing the old subscription products might break the code . 

And if old users downloads the new .apk , how will it will be authenticated to use the service offered by the subscription product no more existing in the list.

Comment: The point is not to remove it from the Developer Console or even from your app code, *it is to remove the old from user sight*. You should offer only the new product to your user, while your app still checks for the old product (thus giving access to the product if the user bought it).

Answer (score 6):

This is not the case now.

You can change the price where for the new users it will update directly and for the old users, you have to wait 30 days with notifying them.

Please check out following link for more information;

[Android Developers: Change the price of a subscription](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#change-price-sub)

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the developer *has* to notify the user about the price change, and get their consent, or whether the developer can rely on Google Play to do this, as described at https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_subscriptions#communicate-sub-price-change.  My reading of this is that it's *optional* to include code that notifies the user with a custom dialog to seek their consent, but that doing so (with a friendly explanation of the price change, e.g. "due to exchange rate fluctuations") will increase the likelihood of the user accepting?

Comment: I'm assuming they only show the notification if the price actually changes but can anyone confirm? like if you sell it in 20 countries but adjusted the local pricing for 2 of them, only users who purchased in the adjusted currencies would receive the notification?

Comment: @drmrbrewer yes it is not mandatory to notify your users about the price change, Google will start doing it 7 days after you changed the price.
Google advice is give an explanation to your user in the 7 days following your price change, and improve your conversion rate.